# How to model this specific flat part and wrap it around a cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, project

I'm wondering what should be the best approach for modeling this specific part:

I was thinking about drawing it in 2D curves then adding some thickness and bending it around the cylinder but it bends quite tricky and I'm not sure how to do it in a best way. Maybe the is some simpler way?

thanks,
Piotrek

[image: desired part]

[image: progress so far]

[image: geometric projections of the part]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can begin with a cylinder, cut its bottom:

[image]

Give it a *Mirror* modifier, extrude the bottom:

[image]

Bevel this edge:

[image]

Add some edge loops:

[image]

Cut the holes:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify* modifier, a *Bevel* then a *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

To do the hole, select 2 faces:

[image]

Inset with <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

Enable the *LoopTools* addon and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Then remove the faces to cut off the hole:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the advise I'll try that, I'm only worrying how to properly bend the "wings" of this object to be accurate

Comment: Hey, I was also wondering how to cut out those hexagonal holes you did? Did you insert face and use some loop tools for that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW03q.jpg

Comment: @Piotrek B. I've editd my answer to explain more in detail

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help! Now I get it!